# Find a solutions for segmentation fault in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, elliptic-curve

I am porting elliptic curve cryptography for contiki os (Based on pure c). I am getting an error of segmentation fault. I used xxgdb to debug and still I can't found a reason why is that. And I do not have clear idea about debug in c. Please help with how get rid of these segmentation faults in c at all times(how to find why this segmentation fault occur).

Here is my source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint32_t NN_DIGIT;
typedef uint64_t NN_DOUBLE_DIGIT;

/* Types for length */
typedef uint8_t NN_UINT;
typedef uint16_t NN_UINT2;

#if defined (SECP128R1) || defined (SECP128R2)
#define KEY_BIT_LEN 128
#else 
#if defined (SECP160K1) || defined (SECP160R1) || defined (SECP160R2) 
#define KEY_BIT_LEN 160
#else 
#if defined (SECP192K1) || defined (SECP192R1)
#define KEY_BIT_LEN 192
#else
#define KEY_BIT_LEN 128
#endif /* 192 */
#endif /* 160 */
#endif /* 128 */

/* Length of digit in bits */
#define NN_DIGIT_BITS 32

/* Length of digit in bytes */
#define NN_DIGIT_LEN (NN_DIGIT_BITS/8)

/* Maximum value of digit */
#define MAX_NN_DIGIT 0xffffffff

/* Number of digits in key
 * used by optimized mod multiplication (ModMultOpt) and optimized mod square (ModSqrOpt)
 *
 */
#define KEYDIGITS (KEY_BIT_LEN/NN_DIGIT_BITS) //5

/* Maximum length in digits */
#define MAX_NN_DIGITS (KEYDIGITS+1)

/* buffer size
 *should be large enough to hold order of base point
 */
#define NUMWORDS MAX_NN_DIGITS

/* the mask for ModSqrOpt */
#define MOD_SQR_MASK1 0x8000000000000000ll
#define MOD_SQR_MASK2 0x0000000100000000ll

typedef struct Point
{
    // point's coordinates
    NN_DIGIT x[NUMWORDS];
    NN_DIGIT y[NUMWORDS];
} Point;

Point pbkey_alice;
void 
NN_Encode(unsigned char *a, NN_UINT len, NN_DIGIT *b, NN_UINT digits)
{
  NN_DIGIT t;
  int j;
  unsigned int i, u;

  for(i = 0, j = len - 1; i < digits && j >= 0; i++) {
    t = b[i];
    for(u = 0; j >= 0 && u < NN_DIGIT_BITS; j--, u += 8) {
      a[j] = (unsigned char)(t >> u);
    }
  }

  for(; j >= 0; j--) {
    a[j] = 0;
  }
}

int ecc_point2octet(uint8_t *octet, NN_UINT octet_len, Point *P, int compress)
{
    if (compress){
        if(octet_len < KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN+1)
      {//too small octet
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
          //compressed point representation
            if((1 & P->y[0]) == 0){
        octet[0] = 0x02;
            }
            else
                {
                octet[0] = 0x03;
                }
            NN_Encode(octet+1, KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN, P->x, KEYDIGITS);
            return KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN+1;
      }
    }
  else
  {//non compressed
     if(octet_len < 2*KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN+1)
    {

        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
            //octet[0] = 0x04;
            NN_Encode(octet+1, KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN, P->x, KEYDIGITS);
            NN_Encode(octet+1+KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN, KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN, P->y, KEYDIGITS);
            return 2*KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN+1;
        }
  }
}

int main()
{
pbkey_alice.x[5] = 0x00000000;
  pbkey_alice.x[4] = 0x21961f69;
  pbkey_alice.x[3] = 0xf02d202b;
  pbkey_alice.x[2] = 0xa4b41f1a;
  pbkey_alice.x[1] = 0x0aa08a86;
  pbkey_alice.x[0] = 0xdf27908d;

  pbkey_alice.y[5] = 0x00000000;
  pbkey_alice.y[4] = 0x378e1278;
  pbkey_alice.y[3] = 0x62836d75;
  pbkey_alice.y[2] = 0x7acb7ca4;
  pbkey_alice.y[1] = 0x0dc0ad13;
  pbkey_alice.y[0] = 0x741e287c;
uint8_t *C;
int C_len = 2*KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN + 1 + 20 + 20;
int oct_len = ecc_point2octet(C, C_len, &pbkey_alice, 0);

}
```

Comment: 'how get rid of these segmentation faults in c at all times' -- Oh if only! You don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: How? Find bugs and fix them. That easy.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Ok, I'm currently debugging a machine control system of about 1 million lines of awful code, written 18 years ago, compiled under a no longer supported compiler, using libraries written by companies that no longer exist, that accvio's when it has run for some number of hours, varying between 2 and 32; none of the boundschecker-type tools can identify the problem. Feel free to come around and show me how easy it is to fix the bug.

Comment: @JimBalter The comment was for the OP, whose case is much simpler. As for your project, it looks like an interesting problem. I'd actually like to try solving one of these.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze c'mon, your comment was frivolous, so please don't try now to treat it as a serious contribution to the OP's question.

Comment: @JimBalter The OP has a small piece of code that can be analyzed and debugged.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Non sequitur. Let's not chat here, ok? Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Carl said, just replace : `uint8_t *C` by `uint8_t *C = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t))` and you'll be good.

Comment: thanks,  now no segmentation fault, but another error occur in cooja simulator...

Comment: Allocating space for just 1 byte probably isn't enough.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't allocated any memory for `C` before you pass it to `ecc_point2octet()`.  That seems like a recipe for just the kind of problems you're seeing.

Comment: thanks for advice here is backtrace
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080484c4 in ecc_point2octet (octet=0x80485d0 "UWVS\350i", octet_len=73 'I', 
P=0x804a040, compress=0) at octtest.c:108
108  octet[0] = 0x04;

(gdb) info s
#0 0x080484c4 in ecc_point2octet (octet=0x80485d0 "UWVS\350i", 
octet_len=73 'I', P=0x804a040, compress=0) at octtest.c:108
#1 0x080485c5 in main () at octtest.c:133